# Java Servlet redirect to page auto calls its form servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

the problem to when I fill in the form it calls a servlet, which displays the correct information, when the user clicks the back button it seems to call the servlet on that page with the value null. How do i make it so it reloads the page so the user can refill in the form.

SetTimeZone.xhtml

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>SetTimeZone</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form name ="SetTimeZone" method="post" action="SetTimeZoneServlet">
            Set Time Zone: <input type="text" name="timeZone"/><br></br><br></br>
            <input type ="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
public class SetTimeZoneServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    TimeZoneBean bean = new TimeZoneBean();
    String city = request.getParameter("timeZone");
    bean.setCity(city);
    String temp = bean.checkCity();
    String value = "";

    if ("error".equals(temp)) {
        value = "Sorry no information is availible for " + city;
    } else {
        value = "The current time in " + city + " is " + bean.getTime();
    }

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet OrderFormServlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<p>" + value + "</p>");
        out.println("<form name=\"SetTimeZone.xhtml\" method=\"post\" name=\""
                + "SetTimeZoneRedirectServlet\"> ");
        out.println("<input type =\"submit\" value=\"Back\"/ name=\"back\">");
        out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

public class SetTimeZoneRedirectServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.sendRedirect("SetTimeZone.xhtml");
}
}
```

The output i get after the redirect back to the page is;
Sorry no information is available for null.

Answer (score -1):

Try Using the GET Instead of POST 
This may solve your problem

Comment: Ive tried this previously i get this error when i change GET to POST. HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Comment: you can override the get method in the servlet and call the doPost(req, res); inside the overridden doGet() Method

Answer (score -1):

By using the `POST` method for your form you may encounter this problem. As @visray suggested, you need to override the `doGet()` Servlet method for the `GET` method to work correctly.

`POST` method should be used when dealing with database changes, so in your case `GET` is appropriate.